# didSelectAnnotationView doesn't call on custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. I have set delegate on mapView
2. I've set setCanShowCallout: to YES
3. Code from my custom MKAnnotationView:

   ```
   - (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
       if (self) {
       self.canShowCallout = YES;
       _pinView = [[CustomPinView alloc] init];
       [self addSubview:_pinView];
    }
   return self;
   }
   ```
4. Code from my VC:

   ```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
     MapAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

     pinView = (MapAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"lol"];
     if (pinView == nil){
         pinView = [[MapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"lol"];
     }
     return pinView;
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong, pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, I'll do it by myself.

1. You should set image to your custom MKAnnotationView with size of subviews.
2. You should set canShowCallout = YES only if your MKPointAnnotation has description string (not nil, or @""), otherwise you should set canShowCallout = NO

After that method didSelectAnnotationView will be called. Hope it helps for someone.